# Geocode returns null address in lollipop

Tags: android

I have a problem in getting the location address from latitude and longitude as I am using the geocoder for getting the address and it is working fine in the MarshMallow and above 5 devices but not working in the version 5 (lollipop) and i want to run my code in the version 5 also. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

> here is my code

```
if (this.geocoder == null) {
        this.geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng), 1);
            if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            address = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            PrefsManager.with(this).save(Constants.PREF_ADDRESS,addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            return addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: a list of Address objects. Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

Comment: So how can i do that ? @Gobu CSG

Comment: @I.d007 did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with dummy lat and lng in android version 5.1. it is working fine.

It is my suggestion for you please debug your code with break points. check is it the issue with geocode or with something else. Please check may be you are getting location for MarshMallow version in permission check block not getting in else part which works for lolipop and other lower versions.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JSharma I debug it so many time.. But i am getting null always and i am testing in version 5.1.1

Comment: Yes! I thought, I'm the only guy facing this issue. Fyi, it is working on 5+ but not in 5. I've fully tasted it. @i.d007 did you solved it?

Comment: @SambitMallick did you find a solution to this?